# How to get Sub-type MIME of an Office document, instead of getting OOXML in Tika

Tags: java, mime, apache-tika

I am using Tika to validate filetypes and make sure no one is trying to send a malicious or fake file under the guise of a genuine one. To do this I am using Apache Tika. However, even if I wrap the InputStream into a TikaInputStream, or using OOXMLParser or OfficeParser, it still returns application/x-tika-ooxml instead of application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document. How do I access or get it to return the sub Type?

```
    public static boolean isValidFileMimeType(TikaInputStream stream, String[] validMimes) {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    try {
        Metadata meta = new Metadata();
        tika.detect(stream, meta);
        String mimetype = meta.get("Content-Type");
        logger.debug("MIME type from TIKA is : [" + mimetype +"]");
        logger.debug(meta.toString());
        //return isValidFileMimeType(mimetype, validMimes);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error validating InputStream: ", e);
        return false;
    }

public static boolean isValidFileMimeType(MultipartFile file, String[] mimeTypes) {
    TikaInputStream in = null;
    boolean isValidFile = false;
     try {
         in = TikaInputStream.get(file.getInputStream());
        isValidFile = DataValidator.isValidFileMimeType(in, mimeTypes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error while validating file mime type: ", e);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                logger.error("Error while closing InputStream: ", e2);
            }
        }
    }
        return isValidFile;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be passing the `TikaInputStream` into the second method, instead it re-uses the original `file.get` one a second time. What happens if you fix it to actually use the `TikaInputStream` you created?

Comment: You are right, that was an edit I did for testing. Going to pass TikaInputStream, as well as change first method to take TikaInputStream and see if that works.

Comment: It still gives ooxml only. I think I tested that before and no change, but at least now I'm for sure passing TikaInputStream

Comment: Try with the standalone single-jar Tika App in `--detect` mode, can that correctly get your file type?

Comment: It does say the correct type. It uses OOXML parser, when I try to `OOXMLParse` in project, it returns `ClassDefNotFound`, though it can find the dependency and the jar is in there. I think if I can get `OOXMLParser` properly working it will run, just need to find out why it isn't working.

Comment: Apache Tika has lots of dependencies, either use OSGi or have a tool like Maven / Gradle take care of it for you. Doing the dependencies by hand is not recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Just import / use the Tika-parsers